# Watermark for text input in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Anyone know if it's possible to set a watermark on a jQuery Mobile text input?

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/forms/texts/index.html

Obviously there are watermark plugins, but I'd rather avoid using plugins if possible, as it's mobile.

`value` sets pre-filled text, but I'd prefer a watermark.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean like, a placeholder?

Comment: Yes, so it seems. But that wasn't in my vocabulary, and watermark was :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use like this

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Type Something"/>
```

A sample here - http://jsfiddle.net/wQ39k/